# merging particular text files in different directories

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have 6 directories. Each directory includes 8 text files. These text files share the same prefix. I need to combine these text files as follows;

Assume, first text file in directory_1 contains files containing the text `abc_1`, directory_2 contains files with the text `abc_2` and so on. Merged text file for the first text files needs to be in this form:

```
abc_1
abc_2
abc_3
..
abc_6
```

The second, third... and eighth text files also need to be combined with the same rule.

Comment: Is the prefix the same *within* directory and different *between* directories? For example, do you have abc_1, abc_2, ..., abc_8 in directory 1 and def_1, def_2, ..., def_8 in directory 2?

Comment: Also do you already know the list of prefixes (if different for each directory)? Do the prefixes have all the same length (e.g. 3 letters) or do they all finish with an underscore?

Comment: prefix is the same within directory and between different directories.  Prefixes have not all the same length.

Comment: If the prefix is the same within directory and between directories then you have the same prefix everywhere. Then how can it not be of the same length if you have only ONE identical prefix everywhere?

Comment: I have not only one identical prefix everywhere

Comment: Ok so it is not the same between directories. Is it always followed by an underscore?

Comment: yes it is always followed by an underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files must be sortable, so assuming the names of the files in each directory end with a number from 1 to 8, such as `foo1`, `foo2`... in one directory and `bar1`, `bar2`... in another and so on, you could use `cat` and a `for` loop to con**cat**enate them:

```
for j in {1..8}; do cat directory_{1..6}/*$j > newfile$j; done
```

(no need to "quote" a variable we know is a single digit) This will print, in, for example, `newfile1`, the contents of

```
directory_1/foo1
directory_2/bar1
directory_3/baz1
...
```

whatever those contents are, and in `newfile2` the contents of `directory_1/foo2`, `diectory_2/bar2` etc

Answer (score 3):

An implicit method (can fail if unrelated files with filename ending with _ and a number are in the same directory) which names each merged file according to the file number:

```
DIRS_BASE=directory_
for ((FNUM=1; FNUM<9; FNUM++)); do
    cat ${DIRS_BASE}[1-6]/*_${FNUM} > merged_${FNUM}
done
```

An explicit method (safer) using a list of prefixes, which names each merged file according to the file number:

```
DIRS_BASE=directory_
PLIST=(abc def ghi jkl mno pqr)
NDIRS=${#PLIST[@]}
for ((FNUM=1; FNUM<9; FNUM++)); do
    PLIST_NUM=(${PLIST[@]/%/_$FNUM})
    cat ${PLIST_NUM[@]/#/$DIRS_BASE[1-$NDIRS]/} > merged_${FNUM}
done
```

Comment: @Zanna I didn't see that the OP edited his question to make it clearer (question was not intelligible first). I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks! I just removed an unnecessary reference to the number of directory in the second method